# How do you load a file whose file name is stored in an array?

Tags: matlab

here is my code:

```
function [] = plotavg (x)
files = dir('*.mat');
for c=1:length(files)
    load files(c);
    d=0;
    if start_month == x
        for i=1:length(data)
            d = d + data(i);
        end
    end
end
```

I don't know how to write it so that the load function loads the file listed in that index of the array

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `for c = files` will work as well. Then you can just type `c.name` in the loop to get the name of the file. Also, you should try the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) for problems like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dir returns a struct with some field names. One of them is "name", i.e. the name of the file. If you type e.g. files(1) in the console, you will see the fields you get for each item in your directory.

Replace

```
load files(c);
```

with

```
load(files(c).name);
```

and it should work.

Comment: Note that the the first 2 elements will give you "rubbish". The first element is `'.'` and the second element `'..'`. This is the fundamental structure of the file system. A `'.'` means "current folder" and `'..'` means "parent folder". The reason these exist is to make it possible to navigate the folders when using command line arguments.

Comment: Yes, but not if you use a filter in the dir command, e.g.  files=dir('*.mat'); will only list .mat files and files(1) will indeed contain the first .mat file in the  directory.